# How to navigate to different screen without showing the screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to navigate from my login screen to the home screen without showing the view. I am trying to do is if from the splash screen if it gets the username from async storage then move to login page ...wherein login page by if the username matches from the POST method in login screen directly login  if not then show the login screen view
here is my code

```js
import React ,{useState} from 'react';
import { 
    View, 
    Text, 
    TouchableOpacity, 
    TextInput,
    Platform,
    StyleSheet ,
    StatusBar,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';



const asdf = ({navigation}) => {

    const STORAGE_KEY = 'username';
    
    const [userName, setUserName ] = useState(''); 
    const [errortext, setErrortext] = useState('');
    
            const retrieveData = async () => {
             try {
               const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
              if (value !== null) {
                var str = value;
                // str = str.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
                str = str.replace(/"/g,'');
                fetchData(str);
                
               }
               
          } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
          }
        };
        retrieveData(); 
    
        const handleSubmitPress = () => {
        
            if (!userName){
              setUserName('')
            //   onChangeText();
              return
            } else{
              fetchData(userName);
            }
          
            
            setUserName('')
            //onChangeText();
            
            }

        const fetchData = (userName) => {
          if(userName){
            let dataToSend = {search :userName}
            let formBody = [];
            for (let search in dataToSend) {
                let encodeKey = encodeURIComponent(search);
                let encodeValue = encodeURIComponent(dataToSend[search]);
                formBody.push(encodeKey + '=' + encodeValue);
            }   
            formBody = formBody.join('&');
            fetch('https://qwert/work/rest/apiofficeapp.php', {
                method: 'POST', //Request Type
                body: formBody, //post body
                headers: {
                  //Header Defination
                  'Content-Type': 
                    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
                    
                },
          
            }) 
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              if (responseJson[0] != ''){
                //alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson[0]));
                 const saveData = async () => {
                    try {
                      await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, responseJson[0][0]['username'])
                      //await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(responseJson[0][0]['username']))
                      //alert('Data successfully saved login page')
                    
                    } catch (e) {
                      //alert('Failed to save the data to the storage')
                    }
                    
                  }

                  saveData();
                  navigation.navigate('HomeApp');
                 

                 setErrortext(''); 

                
                  }else {
                        
                      setErrortext(userName + 'user not found')
                    }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            }); 
          } }
          // const onChangeText = userName => setUserName(userName)
          

   
    const onChangeText = userName => setUserName(userName)

    const { colors } = useTheme();


    // const onChangeText = (val) => {
    //     if( val.length !== 0 ) {
    //         setUserName({
    //             ...userName,
    //             userName: val,
                
    //         });
    //     } else {
    //         setUserName({
    //             ...userName,
    //             userName: val,
                
    //         });
    //     }
    // }


    

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor='#009387' barStyle="light-content"/>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.text_header}>Welcome!</Text>
        </View>
        <Animatable.View 
            animation="fadeInUpBig"
            style={[styles.footer, {
                backgroundColor: colors.background
            }]}
        >
            <Text style={[styles.text_footer, {
                color: colors.text
            }]}>Username</Text>
            <View style={styles.action}>
                <FontAwesome 
                    name="user-o"
                    color={colors.text}
                    size={20}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Your Username"
                    placeholderTextColor="#666666"
                    style={[styles.textInput, {
                        color: colors.text
                    }]}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    onChangeText={(userName) => onChangeText(userName)}
                    onSubmitEditing={handleSubmitPress}
                />
                </View>
                {/* {data.check_textInputChange ? 
                <Animatable.View
                    animation="bounceIn"
                >
                    <Feather 
                        name="check-circle"
                        color="red"
                        size={20}
                    />
                </Animatable.View>
                : null}
            </View> */}
           
            <View>
                  {errortext != '' ? (
                    <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>
                      {errortext}
                    </Text>
                  ) : null}
                  </View>
            
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.signIn}
                    onPress={() => {handleSubmitPress()}}
                >
                <LinearGradient
                    colors={['#eb0c00', '#A80900']}
                    style={styles.signIn}
                >
                    <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                        color:'#fff'
                    }]}> Sign In </Text>
                </LinearGradient>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Register')}
                    style={[styles.signIn, {
                        borderColor: '#A80900',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        marginTop: 15
                    }]}
                >
                    <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                        color: '#A80900'
                    }]}> Register </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </Animatable.View>
      </View>
    );
};

export default asdf;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1, 
      backgroundColor: '#A80900'
    },
    header: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingBottom: 50
    },
    footer: {
        flex: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 30
    },
    text_header: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 30
    },
    text_footer: {
        color: '#05375a',
        fontSize: 18
    },
    action: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#f2f2f2',
        paddingBottom: 5
    },
    actionError: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#FF0000',
        paddingBottom: 5
    },
    textInput: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : -12,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        color: '#05375a',
    },
    errorMsg: {
        color: '#FF0000',
        fontSize: 14,
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 50
    },
    signIn: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 50,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10
    },
    textSign: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  });
```

I not able to navigate to home app without showing the login screen directly

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to use a Splash lib that will create an actual native screen for the splash and you just dismiss the splash screen on the login screen or the main screen.

One lib you may use:

https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

It fairly simple to install and you just need to call this on your Login or Mais screen when its mounted:

```
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

export default class MainPage extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }
}
```

Success on your project.

Comment: I already have a splash screen...where I session validate and what I want when it lands on the login screen when I call retrievedata() it goes to fetch and navigate to the homepage..only thing when I have a data in session it goes to the home screen but it shows the view part of the login screen, I only want a view of login when i don't have data in session

Comment: then you need to put all your validations on the slash screen, you just navigate to login screen if the user actually needs to go there, otherwise navigates to the home screen.

Comment: Okay.. is there not an option to hide the view of the page

Comment: you could do some hacky things like starting the Screen without any content (you can make the whole screen just return an empty <View />), do the validation, if you need you show the content otherwise you just redirect the user without showing the content.